# How to concatenate output data coming out from for loop/function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a data set as a list. From that list I need to find a keyword, and if found, I should be able to extract the complete information of that element.

```
att =['Email/xyz@gmail.com', 'CountryCode/US','CountryCode/UK', 'ID/12345']
```

from the above list, if I search only CountryCode, then the output should come as:

```
['CountryCode/US','CountryCode/UK']
```

Below is my code which I am trying, but it is returning only a single value.

Can some one help me with this code, to return all of the values as :

```
['CountryCode/US','CountryCode/UK']
```

```
def att_func(field,data):
    for i, j in enumerate(data):
        # print(i,j)
        if field in j:
            return [data[i]]


att =['Email/xyz@gmail.com', 'CountryCode/US','CountryCode/UK', 'ID/12345']

field ='CountryCode'

Cntry = att_func('CountryCode',att)
print(Cntry)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error, but I am not getting the desired output, This code is giving output as ['CountryCode/US'] only....

Comment: yes.. I got it. This is because you are returning as soon as single data is getting. I have added answer by modifying your code.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning early in your for loop so you'll never get past the first position where the field exists, you can either use `yield` instead of `return` and make your function return a generator or just use a list comprehension

```
def att_func(field, data):
    return [i for i in data if field in i]
```

Comment: Excellent answer as list comprehension makes this so neat and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Reason : This is because you are returning as soon as single data is getting.

Solution : Collect all data in list and the return collected data.

Try:

```
def att_func(field,data):
    final_data = []
    for i, j in enumerate(data):
        # print(i,j)
        if field in j:
            final_data.append(data[i])
    return final_data


att =['Email/xyz@gmail.com', 'CountryCode/US','CountryCode/UK', 'ID/12345']

field ='CountryCode'

Cntry = att_func('CountryCode',att)
print(Cntry)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
att = ['Email/xyz@gmail.com', 'CountryCode/US','CountryCode/UK', 'ID/12345']
out = [item for item in att if "CountryCode" in item]
```

Done !

Your `att_func` should look like this:

```
def att_func(needle, haystack):
    return [item for item in haystack if needle in item]
```

More on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).